# If a President voluntarily quits after the first month of his second office, can he run again as President in the United States?

Tags: united-states

If a President voluntarily quits after the first month of his second office, can he run again as President in the United States? The limit is a 7 year office, but if you leave in your second term after a month do you still get to run or not? What if the President quits before the beginning of his second term?

Comment: where did you get the "7 year office" limit? There's a seven-year hitch, but that's something else altogether.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Twenty Second Amendment is quite clear on this:

> No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice

In your question, the President has been elected twice - unless of course the President was actually the Vice President (or elsewhere in the line of succession) at the start of the first term, in which case theres other limits:

> and no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once.

So, someone who has held the office of President after being elevated to it rather than elected to it, but served no more than 1 year 364 days of that first term,  could possibly, by the wording of the Twenty Second Amendment, be eligible to resign within their second term and stand again but only once more.

Comment: "no more than 1 year 364 days" should be "no more than two years."  If it's exactly two years, the person is still able to be elected twice.

Comment: That said, such a person would also be eligible for election to another term even if they HADN'T resigned. The resignation is simply irrelevant in their case. What WOULD be interesting is if the person acceded to the office with just over 2 years remaining in the term (say, 2 yrs and 1 mo). That person COULD be elected twice IF they resigned say, on New Years Day, retaking the office 6 weeks later in February for their first elected term. That would be one way to game the system.

Comment: So far, the only time the "two years" rule has come up in practice is with LBJ, who served only 1 year and 2 months of JFK's term before being elected to one of his own in 1964.  He would have been allowed to be elected again in 1968.  But in declining health, and with strong primary competition from Eugene McCarthy and Robert Kennedy, Johnson decided to withdraw from the race.

Comment: @dan04: Another way to game the system would be for someone to be elected as VP, but ascend from VP to President on the first day of his term, then be elected again as VP and ascend again, be elected a third time as VP and ascend, etc. since there's no limit to how many times one can assume the presidency without being elected.

Comment: Indeed LBJ's first stint didn't count, as it were.